# Different time betweenTiny RTC and IDE

Tags: rtc

I have time late in my Tiny RTC when i try to set time at sketch downloading.
Library: RTClib.h

Setup line:

```
if (rtc.lostPower()) {
Serial.println("RTC lost power, lets set the time!");
rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));
```

The problem is that my computer displays 15:45 and Serial.print displays 15:12.
How can i fix that ?

Comment: `__TIME__` is the time the sketch was compiled, not when the board starts running. It was compiled at 15:12, but you applied power at 15:45...?

Comment: I compiled and then load the sketch just after. Why so much delay?

Comment: Try to `Serial.println(F(__TIME__))`. This will show you the time that you attempted to set in the RTC, which is your compiler's idea of the current time when it is doing the compilation.

Comment: The key here is `if (rtc.lostPower()) {` -- That is, if the RTC loses power then *reset the time to what it was back when you compiled the sketch*. If you want to set the time to *now* then you will need to include some mechanism to either query the time from somewhere or allow the user to set the time manually.

Answer (score 0):

I just removed "if" condition and keep `rtc.adjust(DateTime(F(__DATE__), F(__TIME__)));`
Solved!